# PHP how to use recursive array iterator

Tags: php

I have a nested array like:

```
$array = [
   'fookey' => [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [10, 20, 30],
    ],
    'barkey' => [
    [a, b, c],
    [d, e, f],
    ]
]
```

I need to get 'fookey' and 'barkey' as a strings and every child arrays first and second value.

Count of child array may differ, but always have 3 elements.

I'm trying to iterate over that array using RecursiveArrayIterator:

```
$rii = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array));

foreach ($rii as $key => $val) {

    var_dump($val);

}
```

But i'm getting values 12 times and their indexes instead of 4 child arrays and 'fookey' or 'barkey'.
I would appreciate your help!

Comment: You don't seem to need RecursiveIteratorIterator at all for this. BTW, RecursiveIteratorIterator works fine on it's part.

Comment: Would you suggest standard nested foreach loop sir?

Comment: It need not be nested too. You can check with the answers you received now to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you need, but that is how I interpreted your question.

```php
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    echo $key;
    echo $value[0] . ' - ' . $value[1];
}
```

Comment: This gives me nested array. Looks like i can't avoid nested foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

This will iterate and keep the first two elements of each child and merge them together.

```
foreach($array as &$value) {
    $value = array_merge(...array_map(fn($arr) => array_slice($arr, 0, 2), $value));
}
```

results in

```
Array
(
    [fookey] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 10
            [3] => 20
        )

    [barkey] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
            [2] => d
            [3] => e
        )

)
```